# What is the code for each click on a button makes the image 2 times smaller in livecode?

Tags: livecode

I need an easy code for a push button that makes an image 2 times smaller with each click in livecode
the image is 300 width 300 height

Comment: Could you please show example with your code

Comment: when i click on a push button i want an image to be 2 times smaller each time , sorry I  can't give any examples because I have just started learning livecode and I am new to it

Comment: on UpdateScore
   if field "score" > 0 
   then  
      subtract 1 from field "score"   
      remove  2 of width of  image "clickMe"   
     remove  2 of height of  image "clickMe" 
      save this stack

Comment: Don't you need a limit, to make sure that the image doesn't get too small to click on?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the name of your image is myImage

```
set the width of image "myImage" to the width of image "myImage" /2
set the height of image "myImage" to the height of image "myImage" /2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer . It helped so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could do it. Create a custom command handler in your card or stack script:

```
command resizeImage pImgName, pResizeFactor
  set the resizeQuality of image pImgName to "good"
  set the width of image pImgName to the width of image pImgName * pResizeFactor
  set the height of image pImgName to the height of image pImgName * pResizeFactor
end resizeImage
```

In a button, or even in the image object script, write a mouseUp handler:

```
on mouseUp
  resizeImage "imageNameHere", .5
end mouseUp
```

Of course you would put the actual name of the image in place of "imageNameHere".

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,  it was so  helpful

Comment: @Ayla, please upvote answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked out the older anwers and I think they forget to make sure that the image stays in the same location. I'm also adding a `lock screen` command. You may omit this if you think it slows down the button too much.

You can put the `mouseUp` handler into script of the button and the `resizeImage` handler anywhere higher up the message hierarchy or in the script of the button itself.

```
on mouseUp
  lock screen
  resizeImage the long id of img 1
  unlock screen
end mouseUp

on resizeImage theImg
  put the loc of theImg into myLoc
  set the width of theImg to the width of theImg / 2
  set the height of theImg to the height of theImg / 2
  set the loc of theImg to myLoc
end resizeName
```

You need to adjust `the long id of img 1` to make sure it changed the size of the correct image, for instance use `the long id of img id 69456` if the short id is 69456 or `the long id of img "my image"` if the name of the image is "my image".

Comment: That was very helpful . Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please vote for the answer to show your appreciation.